# Word omission in error message

Tags: support, validation

I think "don't" is accidentally omitted in this error message.[image: error message]

Comment: What site? On SO you [have the privilege to retag questions](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions).

Comment: Indeed, that was from SO.

Comment: It's telling you to use the "retag" option to just make changes to the tags. If you want to suggest an edit you need to edit the title and/or body.

Comment: OK, that's confusing. Both from a UI standpoint and the error message. And I "worked-around" the issue by also fixing the title of that question (it just so happened that that was (sorta) needed too). Needless to say I wasn't really falling into a pit of success here.

Comment: @xanadont - as you have just noticed, only in rare cases is there just one thing wrong with a post. If you need to edit for one thing (incorrect tags) you will probably need to edit for spelling, grammar, formatting or some combination thereof. Therefore you should always look at the whole post.

Comment: I would say it doesn't make sense to tell someone they can't do something _because_ they have _other_ privileges; surely the _because_ should be explaining what privileges you _don't_ have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've received this error several times.  I agree with [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111368/word-omission-in-error-message#comment-288740), [Mr. Disappointment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111368/word-omission-in-error-message#comment-288776), and [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111368/word-omission-in-error-message/111370#111370) that the error message is grammatically and functionally correct, if a little obtuse.

However, I suggest that we abolish the 'retag' button and this error message, and allow edits which only affect the tags to go through if the user has the retag privilege. The 'edit' button is more obvious (as [xanadont](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111368/word-omission-in-error-message#comment-288801) also experienced) and I'm trained to use that one as it's the only option available to me on all the other sites I participate on.  The 'retag' button is an MSO-only thing for me.

I understand the argument that the post should be edited completely, but we have the retag privilege for a reason - combine it with the edit option, and this error message will be unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

As ChrisF correctly noticed, you were trying to perform "full edit" of the question, which for users with less than 2K reputation means suggesting an edit. Suggested edit must include "real" change in the post itself (body or title) so just changing the tags results in what you got.

However I agree that adding "To change tags only, please click the retag link" or something along those words will makes things more clear.

Comment: Or, you know, if only the tag section is modified then just automatically and transparently turn that into a pure retag? I'm sure something like that could be worked into the system, but I dunno...

Comment: Valid point @Bolt but this way when the suggesting user will change tags and one tiny thing (e.g. single `i` --> `I`) it will only change the tags, not telling him the suggestion was invalid..

Comment: Yes, I was thinking more of what @Bolt is suggesting. I must admit, I didn't even realize the "pure retag" button was there. I'm a dumb user. My brain scanned the set of links at the bottom and saw "edit". "That must be the one! <Hulk Smash>"